# It seems like laravel boot Trait doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, events, model, traits

Recently I'm having problems with using traits, I created some before and it seemed to work, but now I created another one to take action on a creating event, here it is

```
trait Contributes
{

public static function bootContributes()
{
    static::creating(function ($model) {
        if (!$model->getKey())
        {
            Contribution::create([
                'contributing_id' => $model->id,
                'contributing_type' => $model->class_table,
            ]);
        }
    });
}

}
```

and I included it in multiple models like `use Contributes;` I think there is something I don't know about it.

I tried `dd($model);` inside the trait, it works outside of the event but not inside the event

Comment: By the way, I tried `dd($model);` inside the trait and everything, it doesn't seem to be called at all

Comment: You should include that information within the question not as a comment.

Comment: @Matthew You are right, I added it

Comment: I think that `if(!$model->getKey()) { ... }` and the usage of `$model->id` contradict each other. If there is no key on the model, how can you use it to create a related model? From the logic you should use `static::created` and not `static::creating`, as your related model can only be created after the parent model which includes the trait.

Comment: Ok, I have changed it to `created` and removed `if(!$model->getKey())` entirely. It still doesn't respond at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the above method, I figured this one is a better practice and works a lot more better with laravel:

```
public static function boot()
{
    self::created(
        function($model)
        {
            Contribution::create([
                'contributing_id' => $model->id,
                'contributing_type' => $model->table
            ]);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: I would still want to see further investigation on this topic.